# MagicalRecord and saving a unique object in different blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I have a Core Data entity that has a unique ID and for which there should only be a single instance, and can get saved from parsing the response of different server calls at the same time. The saving is performed using MagicalRecord's saveWithBlock, and during the save I check to see if an entity with that unique ID already exists (with the method's local context). If so I save the new data in the existing entity, otherwise I create a new one, before the merge with the default context.

This doesn't work if I have 2 save operations occurring at the same time, as there is a race condition from creating the unique entity within each block's local context, and each block finishing and merging with the default context, leading to 2 instances being saved. I feel like I'm missing something obvious that I should be doing (apart from making sure these 2 blocks don't run at the same time), so any advice on this issue would be great!